# Creating a new cube with Saiku plugin on Pentaho

Tags: mysql, pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian, saiku

I have installed Pentaho Community Edition 5.0.1 and successfully created a new data source from a MySQL database (both hosted on my PC).I now want to perform OLAP analysis on this data, but am not entirely sure how to proceed (So please provide additional information in the case where it is clear from my questions that I am heading on a wrong path - I am new to OLAP).

The Saiku plugin is installed and I can view the 2 premade cubes (SampleData and SteelWheels). I now want to create one or more cubes referencing the data in the data source that I had previously created, which is where I am stuck. As I understand it, I need to create a Mondrian schema which defines the cube, going by [this](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/getting-started-with-pentaho-bi-server-5-mondrian-and-saiku/) I created the shema for the data source as defined on the same tutorial as

```
<Schema name="testdb">
  <Cube name="Test Cube">
<Table name="testtable">
</Table>
<Dimension name="Date">
  <Hierarchy hasAll="true">
    <Level name="Date" column="date" type="Integer"/>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
<Dimension name="Key 1">
  <Hierarchy hasAll="true">
    <Level name="Key 1" column="key1" type="String"/>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
<Dimension name="Key 2">
  <Hierarchy hasAll="true">
    <Level name="Key 2" column="key2" type="String"/>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
<Measure name="Value" column="value" aggregator="sum"/>
```

The tutorial states that this file can be placed anywhere (I', assuming in the biserver-ce folder or sub folders - any best practices on location?). When refreshing the cubes (by pressing the green arrows icon) in Saiku - big surprise - the new cube is not listed, only SampleData and SteelWheels are options in the dropdown (Pentaho had been restarted etc, no effect). When inspecting the created schema, there is no reference to the created data source, so I have no idea how it can be linked or used by Saiku/Pentaho. This is where I think the problem lies, I need to register this file somehow. I have seen references to a data source definition file ([like here](http://docs.analytical-labs.com/saiku/documentation/configuration/2013/08/15/datasources.html)) which seems to be what I need to do. I cant however find where this file should be placed, what it should be named or any tutorial incorporating such a step. I also find it strange that one has to break out of the usage flow of the Pentaho application to make external files which are needed for following steps - hints that I am doing things wrong.

**In summary:** How to create OLAP cube using Pentaho CE and Saiku from a working data source?

It has been surprisingly difficult to find well documented help on usage of Pentaho CE (with Saiku) and warnings on the numerous issues in the setup, I think verbose answers on this question will be of help to the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For launching the cube into BI-Server you simply has to create 1 cube in pentaho schema work-bench and you have to save the link into what ever location you want to store or create one folder and save it their..

After that you have to publish the cube..

Now if you added the saiku pluggin into bi-server then this newly created cube will list under the steelwheles..

So this is the only procedure you have to follow.. now compare what you did by comparing this steps..

Some-times by restarting biserver this problem will not going to solve so, just refresh the list of cubes (the portion where SampleData and Steelwheels ) are displaying so after that you can see the newly created cube in that list..

Comment: Thanks for the response. You mention that after the schema file had been created and saved, it must be published. How does one publish the schema? Is there any difference in using workbench to create the file instead of a normal text editor, or does both ways result in a schema file that then needs to be published? It seems that the only action that I still need to take is publishing the cube, please explain how to do this.

Comment: never tried text editor one thing, but in schema workbench in file menu publish option is their.. so from their you can directly publish the cube into biserver..

Comment: I used the workbench application and got the publish option in the menu. After using this option, all worked. It is disappointing that there is no documentation or indication that the separate workbench application is an essential step in the creation of cubes. Thanks for the suggestion to use workbench. I would have preferred a more clear and detailed reply which would help others in the future, but seeing as this is the only reply and it did help I'm marking as accepted.

Comment: Actually, Schema Workbench is not required. You can live hapilly defining schemas with a text editor, just follow the mondrian documentation, and on the Data source management adding a new Analysis data source and uploading your XML file when prompted. Schema Workbench is useful, but not required, stricly speaking.